# ¿Cómo usar el dispositivo físico para probar anuncios?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

Tras el cambio de versión de los anuncios de servicios de google, ya no aparece la opción *addTestDevice*. ¿Cómo puedo ver videos extra en un dispositivo físico?

```
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        RewardedAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                adRequest, new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                      //  Log.d(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
                        mRewardedAd = null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull RewardedAd rewardedAd) {
                        mRewardedAd = rewardedAd;
                        //Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded.");
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeramente es importante usar al menos la dependencia 20.0.0

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.0.0'
```

Si estas obteniendo errores similares a:

> Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
>
> MainActivity: onAdFailedToLoad() No ad config.
>
> Ads: Ad failed to load : 3

Como comentas, **ya no existe `addTestDevice()` ya que no es necesario, ahora solo debes definir cualquiera de los [ids de anuncios de prueba](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads?hl=es#demo_ad_units) de acuerdo al formato del anuncio deseado** y **configurar tu dispositivos de prueba**, para esto, busca en el resultado de logcat un mensaje similar al que aparece a continuación.

> I/Ads: Use
> RequestConfiguration.Builder.setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("767285BC5624E2271B5FA80E3B84B74E"))
> to get test ads on this device."

En él se indicará el ID de tu dispositivo y cómo añadirlo como dispositivo de prueba.

```
List<String> testDeviceIds = Arrays.asList("767285BC5624E2271B5FA80E3B84B74E");
RequestConfiguration configuration =
    new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build();
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);
```

Pero es importante también ingresar a https://apps.admob.com/ para crear una App y definir un Ad Unit del tipo que deseamos mostrar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en este caso del tipo Rewarded:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar lo anterior debes esperar para que Google configure completamente el anuncio y puedas realizar la petición del mismo.

El App Id que obtengamos se define dentro de el `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
  ...
  ...
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-618245xxxxx483~3587914693"/>

</application>
```

Este es un ejemplo con el id para este tipo de anuncio:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.rewarded.RewardedAd;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private RewardedAd mRewardedAd;
  private final String TAG = "MainActivity";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    RewardedAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-6182xxxxxxx483/2752511027",
      adRequest, new RewardedAdLoadCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
          // Handle the error.
          Log.d(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
          mRewardedAd = null
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull RewardedAd rewardedAd) {
          mRewardedAd = rewardedAd;
          Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded.");
        }
    });
  }
}
```

No olvides el permiso para conexión a internet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: yo uso la version 20.60 y en el locat me dice esto : D/my ads: No ad config. y no carga el anuncio.

Comment: @Osdward  además de "No ad config", te muestra un codigo (Code)?

Comment: Limpie el proyecto y se reparo el error, ahora en el logcat dice : Ad was loaded pero no se muestra el anuncio, el codigo esta tal cual esta arriba.

Comment: Exacto, espera unos segundos a que se muestre el anuncio no se cargan al instante, espera un poco y revisa si se cargo.

Comment: Nunca lo carga, Que crees que pase?

Comment: @Osdward el permiso para conectarte a internet! :D

Comment: Tambien lo tengo crack., haz una app y pruebalo tu mismo y me dices si esta funcionando.

Comment: yo creo que los anuncios solo se muestran cuando la aplicacion esta en produccion ya que han ya que han pasado mas de 24 horas y en el logcat solo dice  : Ad was loaded , pero no se carga el video